# limit of sequence with $o_{p}()$

Tags: sequences-and-series, probability-theory, convergence-divergence, random-variables, random-functions

I am confused with sequence where $o_{p}$ is involved. Assume we have the following sequence of random variables, defined on the same probability space:
$$
x_{n} = \frac{M_{n}+a}{M_{n}(M_{n}+b)},
$$
where $a$ and $b$ are some positive constants and $M_{n} = o_{p}(\sqrt{n})$, with $o_{p}$ means small $o$ in probability, i.e. $\frac{M_{n}}{\sqrt{n}}$ converges to $0$ in probability.

In addition, we assume that $M_{n} > 0$ and for any integer $K$ we have $\mathbb{P}(\liminf\{M_{n}>K
\}) =1$.

Can one make a conclusion about the limit of $\{x_{n}\}$?

Comment: Even if you consider *deterministic* sequences $(M_n)$, you can have different behaviors. If $M_n=\omega(1)$, then $x_n\to 0$, whereas if $M_n=o(1)$, $x_n\to \infty$.

Comment: I updated the question.

Comment: The assumption you added is equivalent to $M_n$ converging a.s. to infinity. In particular, that would imply $x_n\to 0$ a.s. (regardless of your other assumption).

Comment: converging $a.s.$ to infinity sounds strange to me. I would rather say diverges $a.s.$

Answer (score 0):

We have using a power series expansion, if $M_n$ diverges, that $$\frac{M_{n}+a}{M_{n}(M_{n}+b)}=\frac{1}{M_n}+\frac{b-a}{M_n^2}+o(M_n^{-3}).$$

Say we have $f(x)=\frac{x+a}{x(x+b)}$ and say we are after a power series expansion. We then need a basis function, say we pick $\{x^{-n}\}$. Then we have $$\lim_{x\to \infty}xf(x)=1$$, which implies the first term in the power series expansion is $x^{-1}$. Now to the second term proceed as $$\lim_{x\to\infty} x^2\times(f(x)-\frac1x)=a-b$$ where $\frac1x$ is the first term. Therefore we have the second term to be $\frac{a-b}{x^2}$. The third term is hence $$\lim_{x\to\infty} x^3\times(f(x)-\frac1x-\frac{a-b}{x^2})=b(b-a)$$
and so on.

Comment: hi @Math-fun. I do not understand. Look, $M_{n} = o_{p}(\sqrt{n})$. Why do you say that $M_{n} = o_{p}(1)$?

Comment: You are right, just fixed it.

Comment: could you, please, write it more carefully? Taylor expansion at which point?

Comment: See the edit: I hope this helps.

Comment: please, also check my last update. Therefore, from what I can see, the sequence converges to $0$. Correct? In your first version you wrote that it diverges.

Comment: If $M_n$ diverges, i.e. it gets larger and larger then $x_n$ necessarily gets smaller and smaller and vanishes eventually. I corrected my first version (where I assumed wrongly that $M_n$ vanishes).

Comment: Thank you. I see the idea, though I can not say that it is a rigorous proof...